# Determine shape position with cell

Tags: excel, vba, position, cell, shapes

I have an Excel calendar in which certain cells have a shape on them. I wish to be able to see which cells have a shape and then be able to extract some data.
I've searched a bit and found that the best option was to use TopLeftCell.Row but it seems there's an error on my code. I've copied a code and tried to adapt it, here it is:

```
Sub ActiveShapeMacro()

Dim ActiveShape As Shape
Dim UserSelection As Variant

'Pull-in what is selected on screen
  Set UserSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection

'Determine if selection is a shape
  On Error GoTo NoShapeSelected
    Set ActiveShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(UserSelection.Name)
  On Error Resume Next

'Do Something with your Shape variable
  Cells(Sheet1.Shapes(ActiveShape).TopLeftCell.Row, Sheet1.Shapes(ActiveShape).TopLeftCell.Column).Address
  MsgBox (ActiveShape.Address)

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NoShapeSelected:
  MsgBox "You do not have a shape selected!"


End Sub
```

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: What error do you get, where?  You should be sure to add the worksheet before you use `Cells()` in `Cells(Sheet1.Shapes(...`.  Maybe just `Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Shapes...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error is in:

```
Sheet1.Shapes(ActiveShape)
```

where `Shapes` is waiting for a string (the shape name) while you're providing an `Object` (the shape itself)

so use:

```
'Do Something with your Shape variable
  MsgBox Cells(ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Row, ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Address
```

that can be simplified to:

```
   MsgBox ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Address
```

Moreover change:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

to:

```
On Error GoTo 0
```

and keep watching what's happening in there...

Comment: Well, I'm stuck again. I wanted to use the MsgBox to get the address and get Excel to know the value, with a string for example. I can't extract the address, is there a way to copy directly the address? I've tried to add .Copy at the end, that didn't work (I really suck at VBA)

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't work
AddressCell = Cells(ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Row, ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Column).Address
  AddressCell.Copy

Comment: TopLeftCell is already a Range reference so you can directly use AddressCell = ActiveShape.TopLeftCell.Address (where AddressCell must be the name of a String variable) . See edited code also

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to determine if a range or Shape has been selected and if it is a Shape, where it is:

```
Sub skjdkffdg()
    Dim s As Shape, typ As String

    typ = TypeName(Selection)

    If typ = "Range" Then
        MsgBox " you have a range selected: " & Selection.Address
    Else
        Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
        MsgBox "you have a Shape selected: " & s.TopLeftCell.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

*This assumes that the only things on the worksheet are Shapes and Ranges.*